# How to permanently delete already deleted files in Linux?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

How do I prevent the recovery of already deleted files in Linux (without drastic measures (i.e. reset))?

Comment: The question in unclear. Are you asking about secure deletion? or something else?

Comment: What filesystem? What "file recovery" tools does the interested party have? How valuable is the contents to them?

Comment: destroy  the hard drive by shredding it ... as long as the drive is usable, data recovery in part, or in full is possible

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the shred or wipe commands should do the trick.

e.g. this secure deletes everything under doc.

```
$ wipe -rfi doc/*
```

Ofcourse disc dumping should be good too -> `$ dd`

Comment: `wipe` is ineffective for files that have already been deleted (per the question)

Answer (score 0):

If the file was already deleted, then you have to wipe the free space.

If you're ok doing a single-pass wipe, the quickest way would be:

```
cat /dev/zero > zero.file
sync
rm zero.file
```

Refer to original answer on super user: https://superuser.com/a/19488/9231